# DD WRT wifi repeater new ssid signal not showing up

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, dd-wrt, repeater

MainRouter:
[image]

MainRouter Security:
[image]

Repeater:

[image]

Repeater Security :

[image]

Here, Virtual Interface signal with SSID "Repeater" is not showing up in available wifi list.

When I connect to repeater through ethernet cable, it works fine and connects to the internet too but the virtual wifi signal is not showing up in wifi list.
Any ideas ? Below are configurations

MainRouter:

[image]

Repeater :

[image]

**EDIT** :I  changed the Repeater's wifi security to -> "Disabled" and it showing up but anything other than "Disabled" (eg. WEP, WPA2 etc..) prevents broadcasting signal. very strange!!!

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong, but at least in your captures your AP SSID is the same as your main router ("MainRouter") which might explain why the intended SSID ("Repeater") is not showing. Also, it shouldn't be a problem as AP with the same SSID as the main router extend their network just fine.

Comment: I changed the Repeater's wifi security -> "Disabled" and it showing up but anything other than "Disabled" (eg. WEP, WPA2 etc..) prevents broadcasting signal. very strange!!!

Comment: And when you disable the repeaters security, does it prompt for the main network key?

Comment: Nope. It connects witout asking security key.

Answer (score 0):

I saw many posts related to the problem (not broadcasting SSID with security), some gets it fixed by setting TKIP + AES but some don't get rid of the issue.

However I got it fixed by installing K3X version (mega build instead of mini build). All is working perfectly.